# HTML - How to avoid a text in a cell table that overflow out when the cell is very short?

Tags: html-table

I have something like this in my HTML page:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 20vh; line-height: 16px;">
      <td width="1%" >Not important text in cell 1</td>
      <td width="42%">Important text in cell 2</td>
      <td width="18%">Not important text in cell 3</td>
      <td width="39%">Very important text in cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But most of the time, the window page can be displayed into a small screen. So when the cell is too short (because of the size screen or because the width of the cell can vary between 0 and 5%), the width has no effect and the text in the cell is fully displayed despite of adding `max-width: 1%;`. For the moment, the text is always displayed and the cell adapts his width to the text width. Like this : [Bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HACbx.png)

> How can I do to truncate the text for each cell ?

**NOTICE 1:** The text must be contained on a single line, no wrapping.

**NOTICE 2:** The client browser cannot execute javascript code and he is not connected to internet. That is why the code is generated in full HTML/CSS.

**NOTICE 3:** In some cases, the width could be equal to 0% or 0px. In this case, the text must not appear.

So here is what I am expecting with the value of 1% width for the first cell:

- small  screen: [Good example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzaip.png) VS [Bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pamiv.png)
- medium screen: [Good example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH1zl.png) VS [Bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bbA1.png)

I tried:

```
<td width="1%" style="max-width: 1%;">Text in cell 1</td>
```

And also those CSS styles :

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

But I never success. I am doing it wrong ? Does someone have an idea to do this ?

Comment: Would `min-width` work?

Comment: No, I also tried this one, like this: `style="min-width: 1%; width: 1%; max-width: 1%;"`, but no difference.

Comment: Yes, because you're also setting `max-width`. I meant `min-width` on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution [on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) and a visual example [on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow)

You will need to **add a div in the cell** and then **add those three properties on the div**. The fact is I was already testing `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: clip;` in the `td` but not in a `div`.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 20vh; line-height: 16px;">
      <td width="1%">
        <div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: clip;">
          Not important text in cell 1
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="42%">
        <div style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: clip;">
          Important text in cell 2
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="18%">...</td>
      <td width="39%">...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`white-space: nowrap` -> To keep the text on a single line

`overflow: hidden` -> Do not allow text to overflow a div

`text-overflow: clip`-> Cut the text to avoid overflow in his container